# Running script in background without sticking to shell

Tags: bash, java, shell, jboss, pipe

i want to run a shell script remotely via ssh and the ssh shell should end when the script ends. The script itself runs another script whose output is piped to a log file.

Example:
I run the script run1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
function logpipe() {
    while read line;do
        echo $line >> $1
    done
}

./bin/run2.sh $JBOSS_HOSTNAME | logpipe $JBOSS_DIST/log/server.log 2>&1 &
```

run2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec "$JAVA" -DJBOSS_PID=_$$_ $JAVA_OPTS \
         -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS" \
         -classpath "$JBOSS_CLASSPATH" \
         org.jboss.Main "$@"
```

Now the problem is when i run

```
ssh myhost "bin/run1.sh"
```

the shell gets "stuck" to the script and i only can get it loose by closing it via Crtl+C. I guess the trick is something between nohup and another piping trick but i just couldn't get to it by now.

Comment: Maybe i asked in the wrong direction. The reason i put the logpipe function to run1.sh which leaves me with this unending shell is, that the log will be rotated nightly by jboss, where the file is simply renamed. When i log directly like Guss said, the process will still log into the renamed file and not the new one and the log entries aren't chronological anymore. That's why i use this function. Without the function the script leaves the shell as wished, but has the log entries in the wrong file after one day. But i still want to log, what is going to stdout by the process runned in run2.sh.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to run your script in a "[screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)".

```
screen -D -m run1.sh
```

And then you can catch up the screen with:

```
screen -r
```

Comment: There are two types of users: those that use screen, and those that ought to be.

Comment: removed dead link

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the script actually ends, but if it leaves another program connected to the terminal (by backgrounding it), then SSH will still keep the connection attached.

using `nohup` simply lets the shell know that if an external entity is sending hangup signals, they should be ignored, but it does not actually disconnects the program from the console.

I do not know anyway to explicitly disconnect a program from the terminal, but one thing you can do is send a HUP signal to the SSH session that ran the script using the command

```
kill -HUP $PPID
```

this will terminate the SSH connection and will leave the program running, but the calling ssh client will get an ugly "connection closed by remote host" error message.

Comment: That suggests that the way to do this is to ssh without a tty; can't remember the option for that.

Comment: SSH normally runs remote commands without a TTY (unless you force it with `-t`).  `-T` disables this even when running an interactive shell. So tty or no tty - a running program that is attached to the console prevents graceful shutdown of SSH.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh myhost "nohup bin/run1.sh"
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: It doesn't. It still leaves my hanging in the shell, from where i can only escape through Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're correct about nohup. In run1.sh, try changing the last line to:

```
nohup ./bin/run2.sh $JBOSS_HOSTNAME | logpipe $JBOSS_DIST/log/server.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ssh -t mentioned above, which I think will work, you should be sure to close all of your script's inputs & outputs:

```
ssh myhost "bin/run1.sh > yourlog 2>&1 < /dev/null"
```

All credit to the OpenSSH FAQ, [where](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.11) I found this years ago.

Comment: You can use `-n` instead of `< /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if run1.sh sources run2.sh?:

```
. ./bin/run2.sh $JBOSS_HOSTNAME | logpipe $JBOSS_DIST/log/server.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably file descriptors fd>2 that are still open. Check with lsof.